# Dictaphone app for Android that records at a press of a button

Tags: android

I need a dictaphone app for my [HTC One mini](http://www.gsmarena.com/htc_one_mini-5505.php) to take audio notes.
Features I need:

1. Start recording at a press of a button (say, "volume up" button), maybe long press of a button. It would be nice if it could play some sound so that I know that it did in fact start recording.
2. It would be great if the recorded audio notes could be dropped into Dropbox.

There's a built-in Notes app that comes with HTC One mini; is it worth using?

I need an app that could (if this is at all possible), at a press of a dedicated hardware button, make a recording and drop it into Dropbox. E.g. look a the instruction for the [notes app](http://www.htc.com/www/support/htc-one/howto/365454.html) from HTC. It says: "1. Open the Notes app." That's not what I need. I need my phone to be able to record a note whenever I press a dedicated hardware button, no matter what app is there on the screen. Most likely, the screen will be locked at the time. I don't really know whenever this is possible, but I hope it is.

Comment: Did you ever find (or develop) such an app?

Answer (score -1):

I have been looking for such an app without success myself.

The alternative which I found to fulfill my needs was another device,
the "SONY Walkman", specifically the model "NWZ B35" (it's an old model but you can find them on ebay https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_nkw=NWZ+B135). It is a smallish mp3 player with a recording option, activated by a long press of the record button. I use a special script to backup its audio recording (and to process them in a special order) each time I recharge it by plugging it in a usb port of my laptop.

I use it to record "audio notes" during the whole day (running, walking, working) and even at night (at the side of my bed) and while swimming (keep it in a zipper bag on the side of the swimming pool and record thoughts without opening the zipper bag).

Note: Sony kept upgrading the model making it less and less useful as a voice recorder, until they suppressed the "Record" feature. I have tried more than 20 other voice recorders, without finding the same easiness of workflow :(

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Please did you also do any voice-to-text automated conversion, to have the notes?

Comment: I thought about it and decided against it: My audio notes are in the line of "send an email to (...)" or "search online for articles about (...)", it is faster listening to them than reading a possibly erroneous transcription of them.

Comment: I did invest time in the script to process them: in chronological order within each back-up (usually a day), and in counter chronological order (most recent first) between back-ups. This way I keep intact sequences (E.g. "oh by the way also do this") in a day, but after a long trip without processing audio notes, I process the most recent ones first. I could not recommend such order enough!

Comment: @Alejandro I know, and I apologize for it. I assumed that if nobody answered for more than 7 years, it was ok to put my solution even though it does not fit perfectly the question.